# create mysql table if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

I don't work much with php/mysql, but I need what I thought would be a relatively straightforward task: to check if a table exists and create it if it doesn't. I can't even get a useful error message and there's no table being created in the db. There is obviously something wrong with my syntax.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // 1. CONNECT TO THE DB SERVER, confirm connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<p>Connected to MySQL</p>";
    $mysql_connexn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // redundant ?

    // 2. CONNECT TO THE SPECIFIED DB, confirm connection
    $db = "weighttracker";
    mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<p>Connected to Database '$db'</p>";
    $db_connexn = mysql_select_db($db)or die(mysql_error("can\'t connect to $db"));

    // 3. if table doesn't exist, create it
    $table = "WEIGHIN_DATA";
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM " . $table;
    //$result = mysql_query($mysql_connexn, $query);
    $result = mysql_query($query, $mysql_connexn);

    if(empty($result)) {
        echo "<p>" . $table . " table does not exist</p>";
        $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WEIGHIN_DATA (
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            PRIMARY KEY(id),
            DATE    DATE NOT NULL,
            VALUE   SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        )"
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>" . $table . "table exists</p>";
    } // else

?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: `$db = weighttracker;` <= uh-huh, do => `$db = "weighttracker";`

Comment: Plus, wrap `$table` in backticks in your query, since your table name contains a hyphen. It figures you want to do math `WEIGH-IN_DATA` which translates to `WEIGH (minus) IN_DATA)`. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: *Oh*, and switch your variables for `result = mysql_query($mysql_connexn, $query);` - In `mysql_`, connection comes last; unlike `mysqli_`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thx for the heads-up on my $db typo Fred. Also, to simplify, I smoked the hyphen. Also I changed the query to Marcelo's version, still no joy; if I remove the CREATE query, at least I get confirmation that I'm connected to db, and that the table doesn't exist, but with the CREATE query, a blank page. I'll try to edit my question to show current state

Comment: You're welcome. As per your edit, you have `mysql_select_db($db)` which should read as `mysql_select_db($db,$mysql_connexn)` --- <= scratch that. Hold on...

Comment: Get rid of `mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());` - Keep `$mysql_connexn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");` - Get rid of `mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());` then change `$db_connexn = mysql_select_db($db)or die` to `$db_connexn = mysql_select_db($db,$mysql_connexn)or die`

Comment: Plus a missing `;` at the end of `)"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thx again Fred. Btw, do I assume correctly that if I use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the if/else is redundant?

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at what I posted below, see if that works for you.

Comment: I edited my answer below, so reload it. I forgot to include `mysqli_query` inside it; tested and working. Let me know. @user1613163

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things.

There was a missing semi-colon `;` in and at the end of `)"`

```
if(empty($result)) {
    echo "<p>" . $table . " table does not exist</p>";
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WEIGHIN_DATA (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        DATE    DATE NOT NULL,
        VALUE   SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    )" // <--- right there
```

which would have caused/thrown a parse error, such as:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in...

Amongst other errors as shown in my comments from your originally posted code.

Plus, you were not using `mysql_query` in your table creation.

Here is a `mysqli_` method, where I commented out your original codes.

Sidenote: You're using `ID` for your column in `$query = "SELECT ID FROM " . $table;` and yet you create your table and column as `id` in lowercase; both lettercase must match.

```
<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$DB_HOST = "xxx"; // put your own data
$DB_NAME = "xxx"; // put your own data
$DB_USER = "xxx"; // put your own data
$DB_PASS = "xxx"; // put your own data


$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}



/*

    // 1. CONNECT TO THE DB SERVER, confirm connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<p>Connected to MySQL</p>";
    $mysql_connexn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // redundant ?


    // 2. CONNECT TO THE SPECIFIED DB, confirm connection
    $db = "weighttracker";
    mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<p>Connected to Database '$db'</p>";
    $db_connexn = mysql_select_db($db)or die(mysql_error("can\'t connect to $db"));

    // 3. if table doesn't exist, create it
    $table = "WEIGHIN_DATA";
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM " . $table; // that should be id and not ID
    //$result = mysql_query($mysql_connexn, $query);
    $result = mysql_query($query, $mysql_connexn);


*/


    $table = "WEIGHIN_DATA";
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM " . $table; // that should be id and not ID
    //$result = mysql_query($mysql_connexn, $query); // your original code
    // however connection comes last in mysql method, unlike mysqli
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


if(empty($result)) {
    echo "<p>" . $table . " table does not exist</p>";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WEIGHIN_DATA (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        DATE    DATE NOT NULL,
        VALUE   SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    )");
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>" . $table . "table exists</p>";
    } // else

?>
```

Comment: Many thanks again. This worked. Yesterday was a major frustration because I could create the table in, e.g., SequelPro, but I was stubbornly trying to make it work in context of php, and the query (as I had found it elsewhere on SO) just wasn't taking. Obviously there are numerous changes in syntax, so thanks for the heads-up on object-oriented sql queries, this is new to me. Cheers, Shecky

Comment: @user1613163 You're very much welcome Shecky; I was happy to have helped, *cheers* - Enjoy coding :)

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Actually Philip, the semi-colon is necessary, otherwise it will throw an error such as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in...` - when executing it as PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Woops. I thought it was talking about one for the SQL statement. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WEIGH-IN_DATA (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        DATE    DATE NOT NULL,
        VALUE   SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL )
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else wrong with OP's code? (I found many) - *Plus,* this stands at failing => `WEIGH-IN_DATA` <= See my comments under OP's question, especially [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145574/create-mysql-table-if-it-doesnt-exist#comment39143265_25145574)

Comment: If you want to create a table if not exist, you should use "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST", but first you must check your db connection.. maybe the error is the name of the db should be a string: $db = "weighttracker"; mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Thx @Marcelo. Please see my edited question, I've applied the suggested changes, still no success, no error msg, only blank page