# CANNOT CREATE TABLE MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

I try to create a table with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` but something wrong. I couldn't solve that. Could anyone helps me?

```
<?php
$server     = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "bombus";
$connection = @new mysqli( $server, $user, $password, $dbname ) or die( "ERROR : " . mysqli_error() );
$tablename  = "users";
$newTable   = $connection->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename(
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  userName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  isAdmin TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  companyID int NOT NULL,
  branchID int NOT NULL
)");
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run this code? Are you sure the table doesn't already exist? You have an @ in the line that defines $connection, remove it.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25146296/5513005), might help you... I see you're not checking in the database via PHP if the table exists or not. By your problem statement, I couldn't help much.

Comment: you need to change the password to someother name, password is an inbuilt name, try user_pass and run the script again

Comment: Additionally, when I try to run your query, I get errors on userName VARCHAR(MAX). Changed it to VARCHAR(255) and it worked.

Comment: That connects to database I have tested that removing @ didnt make any difference

Comment: 255 worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in your script. change your create table query like below:

```
$newTable   = $connection->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename(
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  user_password CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  isAdmin TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  companyID int NOT NULL,
  branchID int NOT NULL)");
```

Comment: Way to go! Exactly what was said in the comments on the question.

Comment: So @AliDayan please accept B.Desai's answer in regard to him :-)

Comment: I will go to accept but there is warning says you can accept that in 3 minutes